# Process running on computer after application exit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process, formclosing

I have a question, I created an application on visual studio using C# and Window Forms, but every time it runs, if the application close (either manually by the person or when it reach the end) it continue running on the process of the computer, so if I open and close the application 3 times there will be 3 processes with the same name activated. How can I prevent that from happening? So far the only way for me to close it is going to Window Task Manager and closing it manually, which is a pain...

Any ideas?

Comment: Need to see your code to tell you why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to kill all processes and exit from application then first you need to kill threads in background

```
Application.ExitThread();
```

and then exit from application

```
Environment.Exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Saif's answer which forces background threads to abort, but I'd recommend you manage your threads better. If you have threads that run for an extended period of time, you should have a flag (a boolean that can be accessed from anywhere in your code) that tells the threads they should stop running. This is a safer method than

```
Application.ExitThread();
```

because it allows you to flush and close streams, disconnect your socket connections or tidy up whatever you're doing in your threads.

Answer (score -1):

Well, based on this problem you can check if your application is running on your application startup. That way you only start the process if it is not running:

I´m going to check for example notepad:

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
if (pname.Length == 0)
{
   //The application is not running. Start your process here
}
else
{
   //Your application is running. Do nothing
}
```

Comment: The problem is not that multiple instances of the process are running but that the process doesn't quit when it should. I can't think of any reason for this other than threads that keep running in the background.